# Matlab - calculating max eigenvalue of a big sparse (A'*A) matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a big (**400K*400K**) sparse matrix and I need to calculate the largest eigenvalue of **A'*A**.

The problem is that Matlab can't even calculate A' due to memory problems.
I also tried `[a,b,c] = find(A)` and then transpose by creating a transpose sparse matrix, but although the `find()` works, the sprase creation doesn't.

Is there a nice solution for this? it can be either in a matlab function or in another technique to calculate the largest eigenvalue for this kind of multiplication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If A is sparse, see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/ibTJcwPrqtk) and some discussion in [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html#f6-33214) (basically do it part by part) for a way to transpose it etc.

But now you need to calculate `B=A'*A`. The question is, is it still sparse? assuming it is, there shouldn't be a problem to proceed using the previous technique mentioned in the link.

Then after you've obtained `B=A'*A`, use `eigs`

```
eigs(B,1)
```

to obtain the largest magnitude eigenvalue.