# Octave/Matlab: PCA on sparse matrix: how to get only the most important eigenvectors?

Tags: matlab, octave, pca, sparse-matrix

I am using Octave and have a huge sparse matrix that I have to get the eigenvalues of. However, if I just use a function to get all eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the result will take up way too much space, since the input matrix is sparse for a reason.

How can I get only a limited number of the most important eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`eigs`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/eigs.html) instead of [`eig`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/eig.html):

```
D = eigs(A,k);
```

This returns the `k` largest eigenvalues of the matrix `A`. According to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Sparse-Linear-Algebra.html#doc%2deigs), Octave does support `eigs` for sparse matrices. `eigs` uses different techniques than `eig`, is slower overall, and shouldn't generally be used except in the cases such as the one you describe.

Be sure to check out the options for the `sigma` argument in case you want the largest eigenvalues with respect to their real parts only, for example.

The Matlab documentation for `eigs` is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html).

Comment: @user2339308: Eigenvalues don't exist for non-square matrices -even `eig` will error in such cases. What you need to do is find the square roots of the the eigenvalues of the [Gram matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) `A'*A`, which is square. See this now [very related Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129137/) for some details on transposing `A`. I believe that one can get the same results from [`svd`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/svd.html) and [`svds`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/svds.html), but you should check.

Comment: See [this set of course notes](http://www.math.washington.edu/~robin/courses/554.A11/notes/non-square.pdf) as well.