# Multiplication of Sparse matrix on Matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, multiplication

I am using Matlab R2011a. I have a matrix A which is of size 27*3355432. This matrix has a lot of zeros. I need to compute the comand `eig(A'*A)` but I can't even do the A'*A. I have tried using the sparse matrix `B = sparse(A)`and then computing B'*B but I get the error:

```
      ??? Error using ==> mtimes
      Both logical inputs must be scalar.
      To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead
```

Truth is I am not a Matlab expert. Is there a way to produce such a database?

Comment: Is `A` a logical matrix?

Comment: Not that I know of. A consists of (-1,0,1) elements.

Comment: What @David is asking is, what is `class(A)`? Also, it is the `B'*B` line that produces this error, not `B = sparse(A);`, correct? Show the entire error message.

Comment: The answer to that command is double

Comment: Check if you don't change the class of B by a logical one. Or post your code to be able to reproduce your error.

Comment: You _have_ to use `sparse` matrices for this. Unless you have 90TB ram. If that's the case you should hire a private tutor, since money is obviously not an issue for you. I would have gone with a chef, masseuse and a housekeeper too... Maybe a personal Christmas-present-shopper (since that's no fun at all!)

Comment: Also, posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot. It's only possible to make guesses as the question currently stands... =)

Comment: @RobertP. are you jealous?

Comment: A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129137/matlab-calculating-max-eigenvalue-of-a-big-sparse-aa-matrix